# Servlet + JSP. Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain

Tags: java, css, maven, jsp, servlets

I am new here so I hope to help you and get help if is possible :)

I'm a back end developer but this time I have to fight with a Front end project so I'm using **JSP and Servlets** in a **Maven Web Project** for the first time.
I am not using javascript or others frameworks, just JSP and Servlets.

I'm having the following **error** when I try to run my project in a browser:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/plain: "http://localhost:8081/hupaFIN/css/style.css".

I tried to change the Content-type, new CSS files ... and I have been reading the related threads but I can't find the solution. I hope you can help as can be possible :)

I let here my **files**:

**JSP where I am using the CSS file:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="application/javascript; charset=ISO-8859-1"> -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Java Bean In Servlet 3.0</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/estilos.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h2>Hospital Universitario</h2>
        <h3>Proyecto desarrollado por José</h3>

    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myservlet"
        method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="button1" value="KMeans" /> <input
            type="submit" name="button2" value="DTree" />
    </form>

</center>
```

**CSS file**

```
label {
color: grey;
display: block;
white-space: pre;
}

h1 {
    color: blue
}

h3 {
    color: blue
    font-style: bold
}
```

If it's necessary another file or something, just tell me it!

Thank so much in advance guys :) !

Comment: [I downvoted because an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Anyway, it is most probably caused by the configuration of your servlet container (Tomcat?) or webserver, not interpreting correctly the file extension.

Comment: Thank you @JozefChocholacek for your time. Can you tell me why is not helpful? Maybe, Have I got to install some extension or something???

Comment: click my link, you'll find an explanation.

Comment: sorry @JozefChocholacek I am new here and don't know it that. I have edited the post and update with the code instead of images.